# Python creating a while loop depending on input

Tags: python

So for the past hour or so i've been toiling over this piece of work. I want to add a while loop that brings the user back to the start evertime they input something that isn't a number. However I have no idea where to start on this. I've been trying a whole ton of things but nothing seems to be working for me.

```
try:
    length=float(raw_input("Insert Length of room"))
except ValueError:
    print "That's not a number try again"
try:
    width=float(raw_input("Insert Width of room"))
except ValueError:
    print "That's not a number try again"
else:
    cost=(width*length)*3.99
 print cost
```

Comment: Have you tried this: indent the whole logic inside a `while True:` and add a `continue` statement when you want to redo from the while, a `break` statement when you want to exit the loop...?

Comment: Who downvoted every single answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `while` and `break`:

```
length = 0
while True:
    try:
        length = float(raw_input("Insert Length of room: "))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print "That's not a number try again"

# You'll have a valid float in length at this point
print(length)
```

Comment: Thanks that works but how do I add in the else: at the end now?

Comment: Never mind :) I figured it out I just needed to remove the else.

Comment: @noelpearce you could try putting in miku's answer inside a function, and then have the function return true/false depending on the condition of the while loop. I assume this is for the width*height else statement

Comment: Yeah that's pretty much what I ended up doing.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
dimensions = ['Length', 'Width']
values = []

for dimension in dimensions:
    while True:
        try:
            v = float(raw_input("Insert {} of room: ".format(dimension)))
            values.append(v)
            break
        except ValueError:
            print "That's not a number try again"

length, width = values

cost = (width * length) * 3.99
print cost
```

**Edited** for updated requirements.

Comment: That works the issue is I don't want it to start over again at length if it doesn't get a valid float for width.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do the check for multiple inputs, you might define a function to get the input and check it:

```
def numeric_input(message, numeric_type=float):
    while True:
        try:
            return numeric_type(raw_input(message))
        except ValueError:
            print "That isn't a valid number! Try again."
```

Then:

```
length = numeric_input("Insert Length of room")
width = numeric_input("Insert Width of room")
cost = (width*length)*3.99
print cost
```

That way if the user gives a number for the length, but some non-numeric input for the width, the program won't ask the user to input the length again, only the width.

Answer (score -1):

YOu can do as follows:

```
while True:
    try:
        length = float(raw_input("Insert Length of room: "))
    except ValueError:
        print "That's not a number try again"
    else:
        break
```

If you have multiple questions, you can do as follows:

```
in_data = {
           'length': ['Insert Length of room: ', -1], # the -1 is placeholder for user input
           'width': ['Insert Width of room: ', -1], 
           }


for k,v in in_data.items():
    while True:
        try:
            user_data = float(input(v[0]))            
        except ValueError:
            print("That's not a number try again")
        else:
            v[1] = user_data
            break

print(in_data)   
# example output: {'width': ['Insert Width of room: ', 7.0], 'length': ['Insert Length of room: ', 8.0]}
```